# Type 'FlattenInterpolation<ThemeProps<any>>' is not assignable to type 'FlattenSimpleInterpolation'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

Anyone get this with styled components when using typescript? Im trying to use mixins:

Whenever i use a css tagged template i am told that it is not assignable to type FlattenSimpleInterpolation. Anyone know the correct way of doing this?

```
const extraStyles = css`
  background-color: ${props => props.theme.colors.lightGrey};
`
```

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67270314/tohavestylerule-ts-error-type-flatteninterpolationthemepropsany-is-not

Answer (score 0):

I tried to add type to first css line and not sure how, but the rest of the properties inherits types.

```
export interface SpacingProps {
  margin?: string;
  mt?: string;
  mr?: string;
  mb?: string;
  ml?: string;
  padding?: string;
  pt?: string;
  pr?: string;
  pb?: string;
  pl?: string;

  marginMob?: string;
  mtMob?: string;
  mrMob?: string;
  mbMob?: string;
  mlMob?: string;
  paddingMob?: string;
  ptMob?: string;
  prMob?: string;
  pbMob?: string;
  plMob?: string;
}

export const spacing = css`
  margin: ${(props: SpacingProps) => props.margin};
  margin-top: ${({ mt }) => mt};
  margin-right: ${({ mr }) => mr};
  margin-bottom: ${({ mb }) => mb};
  margin-left: ${({ ml }) => ml};

  padding: ${({ padding }) => padding};
  padding-top: ${({ pt }) => pt};
  padding-right: ${({ pr }) => pr};
  padding-bottom: ${({ pb }) => pb};
  padding-left: ${({ pl }) => pl};

  @media ${mobile} {
    margin: ${({ marginMob }) => marginMob};
    margin-top: ${({ mtMob }) => mtMob};
    margin-right: ${({ mrMob }) => mrMob};
    margin-bottom: ${({ mbMob }) => mbMob};
    margin-left: ${({ mlMob }) => mlMob};

    padding: ${({ paddingMob }) => paddingMob};
    padding-top: ${({ ptMob }) => ptMob};
    padding-right: ${({ prMob }) => prMob};
    padding-bottom: ${({ pbMob }) => pbMob};
    padding-left: ${({ plMob }) => plMob};
  }
`;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should call props like this, because styled components identifies the props under the hood:

```
const extraStyles = css`
  background-color: ${(props) => props.theme.colors.lightGrey};
`
```